# How to implement a circular carousel style in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel, flutter-animation, flutter-pageview

I want to create a circular carousel for images like this :

[image]

The plugin [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)  is not what i'am asking here

I think this is possible to do this with `PageView` and the page controller with index pages but what kind of "math logic" should be implemented to get this result ?

Comment: What is the difference between you want and that library?

Comment: This is not the same animation. The library has a horizontal effect with a scale factor for displaying items. I'm looking for a circular animation with an ellipse configuration (see picture). As far as I know the plugin can't do this

Comment: @nicover Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @vietstone not yet

Comment: I followed the answer and discussion from this question, then I can customize their solution to implement this carousel:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61416154/3d-carousel-animation-in-flutter?rq=4

Comment: thanks for sharing this I'll take a look on this

Comment: @vietstone could you please provide an answer with your custom solution ?

Comment: @nicover I pushed my test code to Github: https://github.com/vietstone-ng/test_carousel. There's no instruction but you can run the code without friction.